# Cannot Resolve Symbol 'PageStatus'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to migrate to gradle but I keep encountering errors. Here I cannot Resolve Symbol for PageStatus which is a class under model

[image]

If I import PageStatus I get "cannot resolve symbol 'model'"

[image]

The github branch is here:
https://github.com/jackygrahamez/MayDay/tree/gradle2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your project directory structure is problemtic
here is the path to the model directory

> /app/src/main/java/main/java/com/mayday/md

but it is supposed to be

> /app/src/main/java/com/mayday/md

Comment: Thanks, I ended up changing each package name prefix to `main.java.com.mayday.md.` but I still have a many issues. I'll back out and try changing the project directories